# CakePHP - Automatically populate form fields from model

Tags: forms, cakephp

I thought the form helper did this already, but can the fields in my form automatically be populated with values from the model or do I have to set them all as template variables and set them all as the value of each field manually?

The form is for a user profile, so I just want it to put the user's names, email, etc in the correct form fields automatically.

Comment: tip: let cake bake your templates! this way you learn how it is done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for example: in controller `$this->data = $this->Model->find('first',array(...));`

in view:

> ```
> $this->Form->create('Model');
>  $this->Form->input('field1');
> ...
> $this->Form->end('Save');
> ```

Comment: When should I be populating the controller data?  Before filter?  What is the norm?

Comment: in the action method. If you are new to cake, take a look at this: http://book.cakephp.org/view/1522/Code-Generation-with-Bake You can learn the Cake convention by looking at the generated code.